# Spring Boot, Elastic Beanstalk error, no issue from the IDE

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently using continuous integration in order to automatically set up and configure the servers. Unfortunately I'm running into issues when the Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat 8 initializes. I get the following error only when running from AWS, it runs fine in my ide:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilterBefore(HttpSecurity.java:1112) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at uk.co.thinkinnovate.security.WebSecurityConfig.configure(WebSecurityConfig.java:41) ~[WebSecurityConfig.class:na]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:199) ~[spring-security
```

And the block of code with the issue:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(tokenProcessingFilter(),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new SimpleCORSFilter(),
                    AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().exceptionHandling();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter tokenProcessingFilter() {
    System.out.println("Getting token processing filter.");
    System.out.println(this.tokenBasedRememberMeService);
    return this.tokenBasedRememberMeService;
}
```

Why is the TomCat version not autowiring the tokenBasedRememberMeService but my Spring Boot application is?

Thanks guys.

Edit:
Just a weird note: "Getting token processing filter" only calls in the AWS app and is null whereas in the IDE and Spring Boot it does not appear.

I feel I'm missing some key concept here.

Comment: Can you show the code that's assigning a value to `tokenBasedRememberMeService`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was so simple!

Make sure your application class `extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements InitializingBean`